# Can't install anything with npm (react)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

I have cloned the Hot Reload Boilerplate (https://github.com/gaearon/react-hot-boilerplate) for my first react project.

Some days ago could install React Router using `npm install --save react-router`. But now I would like to install dependencies like Axios to get data using JSON (https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios), or this ReactCSSTransitionGroup from https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/animation.html, but when I run `npm install axios` I keep getting these errors:

```
npm ERR! Darwin 15.6.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "--save" "axios"
npm ERR! node v4.5.0
npm ERR! npm  v2.15.9
npm ERR! code EPEERINVALID

npm ERR! peerinvalid The package react@0.14.8 does not satisfy its siblings' peerDependencies requirements!
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer react-dom@0.14.8 wants react@^0.14.8
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer react-router@3.0.0 wants react@^0.14.0 || ^15.0.0
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer react-addons-css-transition-group@15.3.2 wants react@^15.3.2

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/Ludo/Documents/sites/react/FirstApp/npm-debug.log
```

And also when I run something like `npm i` I get these errors:

```
npm ERR! Darwin 15.6.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "i"
npm ERR! node v4.5.0
npm ERR! npm  v2.15.9
npm ERR! code EPEERINVALID

npm ERR! peerinvalid The package react@0.14.8 does not satisfy its siblings' peerDependencies requirements!
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer react-dom@0.14.8 wants react@^0.14.8
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer react-router@3.0.0 wants react@^0.14.0 || ^15.0.0
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer react-addons-css-transition-group@15.3.2 wants react@^15.3.2

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/Ludo/Documents/sites/react/FirstApp/npm-debug.log
```

What does this mean, and how can I fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: Try update your `npm` package to version 3 or higher.

Answer (score 3):

You're using an old version of `npm` (2.15.9). Run this to update it...

```
$ npm install -g npm
```

Then attempt to install your dependencies again.

Comment: Seems I have uninstalled npm right now haha,

`Ludos-iMac:FirstApp Ludo$ npm install
-bash: /usr/local/bin/npm: No such file or directory`

Comment: Nice. If you need it.. [How to install NPM](http://blog.npmjs.org/post/85484771375/how-to-install-npm)

Comment: Downloaded and installed NodeJS again, got v3.10.8 now. 
Now I'm getting this error: `react-hot-boilerplate@1.0.0 /Users/Ludo/Documents/sites/react/FirstApp
├── axios@0.15.2 
└── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY react@0.14.8`

Comment: Think I need to update my react or something? Is that possible? How do I do that?

Comment: I would go ahead and delete your `node_modules` folder in your project, and then attempt to `npm install` everything.

Comment: Removed node_modules folder, ran `npm install` again, ran `npm uninstall react react dom`,  and then ran `npm install react react-dom`. It seems to work again now :). Thanks sir!

Comment: why do you keep insisting with npm? Use Yarn instead. https://yarnpkg.com/

Comment: I'm a newly converted Yarn fan, but I didn't want to just say "use Yarn" without someone understanding what's going on under the covers, especially people newer to npm/react.

Comment: Updating npm just solved axios installation problem for me.

Comment: For the confused reader; the lines above `npm ERR! code EPEERINVALID` show that the npm and node versions are vastly mismatched, updating npm as shown here is the fix for this error most of the time one sees it.

Answer (score 0):

PS C:\Users\a\Desktop\project 1> npm version
{
npm: '8.3.0',
node: '17.3.0',
v8: '9.6.180.15-node.12',
uv: '1.42.0',
zlib: '1.2.11',
brotli: '1.0.9',
ares: '1.18.1',
modules: '102',
nghttp2: '1.45.1',
napi: '8',
llhttp: '6.0.4',
cldr: '40.0',
icu: '70.1',
tz: '2021a3',
unicode: '14.0',
ngtcp2: '0.1.0-DEV',
nghttp3: '0.1.0-DEV'
}
PS C:\Users\a\Desktop\project 1> npx create-react-app my-app
Need to install the following packages:
create-react-app
Ok to proceed? (y) y

You are running `create-react-app` 4.0.3, which is behind the latest release (5.0.0).

We no longer support global installation of Create React App.
Please remove any global installs with one of the following commands:

- npm uninstall -g create-react-app
- yarn global remove create-react-app

https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started/

PS C:\Users\a\Desktop\project 1> npm update

up to date, audited 1 package in 3s

found 0 vulnerabilities
PS C:\Users\a\Desktop\project 1> npx create-react-app my-app
Need to install the following packages:
create-react-app
Ok to proceed? (y)

You are running `create-react-app` 4.0.3, which is behind the latest release (5.0.0).

We no longer support global installation of Create React App.
Please remove any global installs with one of the following commands:

- npm uninstall -g create-react-app
- yarn global remove create-react-app
  The latest instructions for creating a new app can be found here:
  https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started/

PS C:\Users\a\Desktop\project 1> npx clear-npx-cache
Need to install the following packages:
clear-npx-cache
Ok to proceed? (y) y
PS C:\Users\a\Desktop\project 1> npx create-react-app my-app
Need to install the following packages:
create-react-app
Ok to proceed? (y) y

this will work   clear-npx-cache

Answer (score -2):

if you have turned on auto save , try unchecking that.

Comment: You should provide significantly more detail in your answer to avoid downvotes. If you scan the question slightly more thoroughly you would see that the question asker has a node vs npm version mismatch, hence `invalid peer`